# How to mutually exclude two (or more) boolean flags using json shema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

```
{ flag1: true, flag2: false } -> ok
{ flag1: false, flag2: true } -> ok
{ flag1: true } -> ok
{ flag2: true } -> ok
{ flag1: false, flag2: false } -> ok
{ } -> ok
{ flag1: false } -> ok
{ flag2: false } -> ok
{ flag1: true, flag2: true } -> NO!
```

I want validation to fail only if both `flag1` and `flag2` are equal `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify exactly that constraint using `not`:

```
{
    "not": {
        "required": ["flag1", "flag2"], // both flags are present
        "properties": { // Each flag is equal to true
            "flag1": {"enum": [true]},
            "flag2": {"enum": [true]}
        }
    }
}
```